# How to align text sideways using css transform

Tags: html, css

I would like to have the `div` with a text as shown in the image.

I have managed to make it this like.But i am sure that it is not the right way to do this.

Html

```
<div id = "bar">
<div class = "text">COMPETENCY</div>
```

Css

```
    #bar{
    height:200px;
    width:40px;
    background:dodgerblue;
    color:black;
    position:relative;
}

    .text{
         color:white;
        -webkit-transform:rotate(270deg);
        width:100%;
        position:absolute;
        top:100px;

    }
```

I have achieved  what is there in this image using this code.But i need a better way to do this.Can some one help me with this.

Image:[image]

[FIDDLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/C2wGk/)

Comment: What is the problem with that solution ? Sounds Ok, really. Maybe you intent to use that `div` is a particular case ?

Comment: @ClémentMalet:Its positioned absolute.Try giving a background color to the inner `div` .You will understand the problem

Comment: Why not simply like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/C2wGk/5/)? Are you particular about that markup structure for some reason?

Comment: @Harry:THe solutiuon you provided is fine man!!.i was just checking the other answers  i received.Thanks for your efforts man!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to simplify the markup and use only one element, you can do this :

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/C2wGk/10/)**

*HTML :*

```
<div id = "bar">COMPETENCY</div>
```

*CSS :*

```
#bar{
    width:180px;
    height:40px;
    line-height:40px;
    text-align:right;
    padding-right:20px;
    background:dodgerblue;
    color:black;
    position:relative;
    color:white;

    -webkit-transform-origin : 100% 0;
    -ms-transform-origin : 100% 0;
    transform-origin : 100% 0;

    -webkit-transform:rotate(-90deg) translateY(-200px);
    -ms-transform:rotate(-90deg) translateY(-200px);
    transform:rotate(-90deg) translateY(-200px);
}
```

Comment: :Thanks for your answer

Comment: @Shadow don't forget the vendor prefix for IE9 and the valid transform declaration. (updated my CSS with them)

Answer (score 1):

That's the right way, and you can play with `transform-origin` to get a better result :

```
#bar{
    height:200px;
    width:40px;
    background:dodgerblue;
    color:black;
    position:relative;
}
.text{
     color:white;
    -webkit-transform:rotate(-90deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: right top;
    position: absolute;
    right: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    padding: 0 20px;    
    background: tomato;    
}
```

[**Updated JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/C2wGk/7/)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this as another approach also:

**HTML:**

```
<div id = "bar">COMPETENCY</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#bar{
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 20px;
    background:dodgerblue;
    -webkit-transform:rotate(-90deg);
    color: white;
    width: 250px;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/C2wGk/9/)